# Not able to change Dynamic Web Module 3.1 in eclipse mars

Tags: java, eclipse

Can any one advice how to resolve below error? I'm trying to change project facet Dynamic web module to `3.1` in `eclipse mars` .

Please find screen shot below of this issue,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue got resolved when I uncheck the tick box for Dynamic Web Module -> Apply, then did a Maven Update on the project.